# Is it possible to insert a JSON into AMQP?

Tags: json, data-structures, size, amqp

And furthermore, is it possible for that JSON to be 5MB in size?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean, can you put a JSON payload into an AMQP message? If so, the answer is absolutely. Your message is a blog of bytes, those bytes can be anything.

As far as the limits on the message size is concerned, I think you'd be limited purely by your resources. I can't see why a 5mb message should be an issue. Whether it's practical or not is another matter.